# Double Bug - About Google account and login system

Tags: bug

Username: JerryLum (That's me)

Google mail: jerry@gmail.com (It is fake, for show only)

---

What is my test step:

1. Go to stackoverflow.com home page
2. Login to http://stackoverflow.com using google account 'jerry@gmail.com'
3. Login successful to 'JerryLum'
4. Goto http://stackoverflow.com/users/9887492/jerry-lum user page
5. Click 'Edit Profile & Settings' > 'MyLogins' > 'add more logins...'
6. 'Email' input set to 'amy@gmail.com' and 'password' input set to 'abcd1234'
7. Goto amy@gmail.com google mail page to confirm the mail
8. Go back to 'JerryLum' 'My Logins' page
9. Remove Google account 'jerry@gmail.com'
10. Logout of Stack Overflow
11. Goto stackoverflow.com home page
12. Click signup with Google account
13. Select google mail 'jerry@gmail.com'
14. Fill the information and click 'Submit'
15. Goto the error page
16. Goto stackoverflow.com home page
17. Login to http://stackoverflow.com using google mail 'jerry@gmail.com'
18. Welcome back to 'JerryLum'

### First Bug:

After unlinking 'jerry@gmail.com' google account, register a new account using same google mail will auto relink 'JerryLum' account.

I think it is because 'jerry@gmail.com' and 'JerryLum' account email are same. So the server knows it was the same person and auto relink the account. But No!!!

1. I use 'amy@gmail.com' to register Local Login System. Different address, the system can't compare it.(Step 6)
2. It is smart! It knows I am the same person! So you can just help me relink it and not take me to register page.

### Second Bug:

Can you find that my Stack Overflow account id is 9887492? I register this account about two years ago. So the original id is 56xxxxx. Why?

On step 15. Sometimes the program continues and takes me to page 2 registration form. It affects:

1. Update the 'JerryLum' account id.
2. Change my name on the registration form and break the rename limit. (Display name may only be changed once every 30 days.)
3. Change account profile image. It provides by http://imgur.com, Stack Overflow spends money for it. The system should limit one account to one image. The bug may break the limit.

---

I tested many times and it always happened.

I hope I am wrong because it is about system account.